# Rename the process of a node.js script from node-default

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a few scripts using Node.js which are designed to run in the background. They work fine but there's a minor inconvenience: When I look in the system monitor, the process is named "node-default". I'd like to use a custom name so I can differentiate between multiple JS processes. Does Node provide a builtin function to achieve this for your applications?

Comment: "system monitor" ... what operating system is this?

Comment: I use Linux (openSUSE Tumbleweed). My desktop is KDE and the monitor (KSysGuard) is typically referred to as the System Monitor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change `process.title`:
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_title

```js
process.title = "MyCustomName";
```

Unfortunately that won't help if you're launching processes using something like `pm2` and then debug them using Chrome's DevTools (connecting to node processes). DevTools will show some other file name then.

Comment: Thank you. So I simply add this directly to my script? I launch the script using the command "node ./myscript.js".

Comment: It works on Linux at least. So, `ps` command should output `MyCustomName` instead of `node ./myscript.js`.

Comment: Confirming that this solved it, works exactly as intended. Thanks.